# SharePoint Designer Encountered an error Verifying Form Template

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Good Morning

I have created many workflows, so i know how to do it. Recently, i started getting this error. I have even went back to a fresh site collection, made a simple workflow of "Send an email", thats it, just send an email.

No matter what i do, i keep getting this error saying "An Unexpected error has occurred while verifying the form template"

I installed a fresh site collection under a new site, and the "Send an email worked" so, i am not sure what i have done on this other site.

Can someone please give me some places to look.

This is driving me crazy

Thanks

OK, i cant post a screenshot because i do not have 10 reputation points, so, i hope i have explained it well enough

Comment: Also, Only using SP designer. not using Infopath

Comment: Also, just to follow up, I went back to the one that did work, and took a look at the workflow inside SP Designer, under the "Forms" section, there is now a "send email.aspx", under the forms section of the one that does not work, there is nothing. I am guessing that might be the problem, SP Des is not creating this form??? Maybe

Comment: got any solution?